# Pandas: pct_change across years for same day and month

Tags: python, pandas

I have datetime-indexed data in a `DataFrame`. For each date, I would like to divide that number by the number from the previous year (at the same day and month). February 29th can be ignored.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000), index=idx)
```

Here's the value of `df` for four exemplary values:

```
In [11]: df.iloc[0:2]
Out[11]: 
            0
2000-01-01  0
2000-01-02  1

In [12]: df.iloc[366:368]
Out[12]: 
              0
2001-01-01  366
2001-01-02  367
```

My expected output would be missing values for 2000, and for 2001:

```
2001-01-01  (366-0)/0=Inf (or Nan)
2001-01-02  (367-1)/1=366
```

My approach was `df.pct_change(freq='Y')`, but that simply raises `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. My expected output in this sim

How else could I achieve this?

Comment: `df.groupby([df.index.month,df.index.day])[0].pct_change()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Did you try it with the sample data? For me, it gives the following output: `In [13]: df.groupby([df.index.month,df.index.day])[0].pct_change()
Out[13]: 
2000-01-01         NaN
2000-01-02         inf
2000-01-03    1.000000
2000-01-04    0.500000`

Comment: @QuangHoang I take that back, I was on `pandas=0.23`. Installing the new version made it work!